# Ticket amount resolves to Null in Django Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a simple TicketForm which is a Django Form. I want to override the cleanfield methods in Django 1.8

```
class TicketForm(forms.Form):
    ticket_amount = forms.DecimalField(label="Ticket Amount", required=True)
    name = forms.CharField(label="Name",required=False)

def clean_ticket_amount(self):
    ticket_amount = self.cleaned_data.get('ticket_amount', None)
    if ticket_amount <= 0.00:
        raise forms.ValidationError("Ticket values cannot be below $0.00")

def save(self):
    print(self.cleaned_data)
    #some other code
```

When I do something like `print(self.cleaned_data)` I get an output as so:

```
{'name': "some_name", 'ticket_amount': {...}}
```

And then I cannot process it. Otherwise I've seen the `'ticket_amount'= NoneType` error. Did I implement the clean methods wrongly?

Comment: post the output of `print(self.cleaned_data)`

Comment: NA: try adding `return ticket_amount` at the last in your `clean_ticket_amount` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to put `return ticket_amount` at the end of the method.